# Reset custom system cursor to normal

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-c++

i change the system cursor with SetSystemCursor but when i try to reset the system cursor to nornal with DestroyCursor nothing happens !!

Any ideas ?

Thanks !

Comment: Why do you use an API for that? [Cursor static class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.aspx) doesn't work for you?

Comment: Normally you'd save the curren cursor, change it, and then when done set it back to wat it was with another call to SetSystemCursor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As documented, the SetSystemCursor() function already destroys the passed cursor so destroying it again isn't going to have any effect.

You'll need to store a copy of the old cursor so you can restore it later:

```
// Global Variables:
HCURSOR hOldCursor;
...
   hOldCursor = CopyCursor(LoadCursor(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_ARROW)));
   HCURSOR hNewCursor = CopyCursor(LoadCursor(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_MYCURSOR)));
   SetSystemCursor(hNewCursor, OCR_NORMAL);
```

And restore it like this:

```
SetSystemCursor(hOldCursor, OCR_NORMAL);
DestroyCursor(hOldCursor);
hOldCursor = NULL;
```

Note the considerable pain you cause when your program terminates without restoring the cursor.  As experienced by me testing this code.  Changing system cursors is quite unfriendly since it has a global effect on all other programs that run on the desktop.

Answer (score 8):

Alternatively, you can restore system cursors to defaults like this:

```
SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETCURSORS, 0, NULL, 0);
```

where `SPI_SETCURSORS` is defined as `0x0057`, as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)